# Visualization of p-adic numbers

Tags: roots, projective-geometry, p-adic-number-theory, visualization

I try to understand and get a feeling which gaps p-adic numbers fill to complete $\mathbb{Q}$.

In the course of this I depicted (for $p = 2$) the "base" $\{p^k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ with respect to which every p-adic number can be written

$$ n = \sum_{i = m}^{\infty}a_i p^i$$

with $a_i \in \{0,\dots p-1\}$ – first on the real line (black dots) and then its "projection" on the circle with center $i$ and radius $1$ (blue dots).

[image]

It appears as if the ever smaller p-adic numbers will fill "continuously" the circle near $0$ while the ever bigger p-adic numbers will fill "continuously" the circle near $\infty$.

There is an astonishing symmetry in this picture (at least for me): If we draw lines (yellow) through the points on the circle corresponding to $p^{1+k}$ and $p^{1-k}$ these lines are parallel:

[image]

I wonder what this might mean – and if such kind of visualization makes sense at all?

---

You may wish to compare the pictures above with the usual drawing of perspective (giving rise to real projective spaces):

[image]

<sub>[**Side question:** What does the original curve in the plane look like that gives rise - in projection - to the circle? Is it a straight line, a parabola or a hyperbola? Depending on what? (I didn't try to check, but what else?)]</sub>

And finally with some roots of unity:

[image]

---

This picture depicts the (maybe superficial and not "deep") symmetry between $0$ and $\infty$ as is discussed in the comments:

[image]

But the picture for the roots of unity is symmetric, too:

[image]

Comment: Anyway, I'm a bit pessimistic about attempts at trying to visualize $p$-adics using pictures based on real numbers. The $p$-adics are just totally different kind of animals. Consider that $\lim_{n\to\infty}p^n=0$ in the $p$-adics for starters.

Comment: There's somehow a symmetric role played by $0$ and $\infty$: In the Euclidean metric $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p^n= \infty$, in the p-adic metric $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p^n= 0$ (somehow being the distance to "the point at infinity"?) (How does the projective limit $\lim_\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_p$ fit into this context?)

Comment: The role isn't really that symmetric. For any real number $r_1$ and $p$-adic number $r_2$, there is a sequence of rationals which converges to $r_1$ in $\mathbb R$ and to $r_2$ in $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: @Wojowu: I added another picture which somehow supports my talking of a "symmetry", and I have to admit: I still cannot **see** why the roles *"aren't really that symmetric"* - they **seem** to be. (But this may only point to the "limits of visualization".)

Comment: I think that this: http://www.nt.th-koeln.de/fachgebiete/mathe/knospe/p-adic/ is a much better visualisation of the "ordering" in the $p$-adic world. If you put the rationals on the number line as you do, you are already implicitly using the normal archimedean distance. Those pictures instead show how the countably many discrete points which make up $\Bbb Z$ are "reshuffled" according to $p$-adic distance, and *then* gaps get filled in by completion. (Notice that one could do those pictures for $\Bbb Q$ as well as for $\Bbb Z$, actually I would like if somebody did that ...)

Comment: Whether this is a "much better visualization" is in the eye of the beholder. It looks nice - I admit -, and it probably reveals a deeper truth (than my visualiziation does), but at the same time, it's much harder to grasp: What does it want to tell me - and how?

Comment: As far as I can tell Knospe uses disks to show distance.  The closer two integers are to each other $p$-adically the smaller is the disk they share.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Thanks anyway for the beautiful link which shows pictures evolving like a bud (= Knospe;-)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Nevertheless, there might be *some* "truth" in my pictures? Definitely not the *whole* truth, but a *partial* one?

Comment: Final remark: I guess that Knospe's visualizations are better suited for $p > 2$ while  my visualization is better suited for $p = 2$.

Comment: E.g. in the first picture, now draw the points of the sequence $a_n = 2^n+1$ for $n \in \Bbb N$, and the corresponding ones on the circle. For $n \to \infty$, they "fill the circle near $\infty$" as well. But $2$-adically, the $a_n$ go to 1. Repeat for $a_n = 2^n+17$ (goes to 17). Or $3^n-1$ (does not converge, but has a subsequence that goes to -1). They'll all fill the circle near $\infty$, but the extremely different $2$-adic behaviour of these sequences is not visible in that picture. But if you look at these sequences in Knospe's visualisation, you see the different behaviours.

Comment: Upshot: The circle projection visualises a slightly upgraded version of the archimedean structure of $\Bbb Q$, which is still very far away from the geometry / topology  of $\Bbb Q$ with any $p$-adic metric. I claim: If the goal is to visualise which numbers are close to each other $p$-adically, the circle projection tells us nearly nothing, certainly far less than Knospe's pictures.

Comment: Coming late to this discussion, I think that there are certain totally disconnected Julia sets that look much more like the $p$-adic numbers, if you have the correct match between the function being iterated and the choice of $p$.

Comment: Also cf. https://mathoverflow.net/a/51912/27465.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Thanks a lot for your comments and hints - I really appreciate them a lot. But allow me one remark: Knospe's  pictures work truly only with the numeric labels on it - if I couldn't see the numbers the pictures wouldn't tell me something about p-adic numbers - just about nice self-similar patterns.

Comment: @HansStricker That's not true. This is analogous to if I draw a number line without labeling the real numbers on it. You get a sense of what the metric between points looks like, regardless of where you've placed the origin. Just as you can take some unmarked line in the real world and start labeling points on it calling them real numbers in a consistent way (i.e. not placing 3 between 1 and 2), you can do the same with these pictures and start to arbitrarily label p-adic points on them consistent with the metric (i.e. not placing p closer to 1 than 0).

Comment: @Steven: You are right, thanks.

Comment: I do not understand what your 'side question' asks. How does anything in the projection give rise to the circle? Isn't the circle simply the image of the projection?

Answer (score 2):

View the projection as a map from the real line to the circle in $\Bbb{R}^2$ with center $(0,1)$ and radius $1$. Then the point $r\in\Bbb{R}$ is mapped to the intersection of the line $2x+ry=2r$ and the circle  $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$, which is
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{4r}{r^2+4},\frac{2r^2}{r^2+4}\right).$$
Now let $p$ be a prime number. The line through the projections of the points $p^{1+k}$ and $p^{1-k}$ has slope
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\frac{4p^{1+k}}{(p^{1+k})^2+4}-\frac{4p^{1-k}}{(p^{1-k})^2+4}}
{\frac{2(p^{1+k})^2}{(p^{1+k})^2+4}-\frac{2(p^{1-k})^2}{(p^{1-k})^2+4}}
&=&\frac{4p^{1+k}((p^{1-k})^2+4)-4p^{1-k}((p^{1+k})^2+4)}
{2(p^{1+k})^2((p^{1-k})^2+4)-2(p^{1-k})^2((p^{1+k})^2+4)}\\
&=&\frac{(4p^{3-k}+16p^{1+k})-(4p^{3+k}+16p^{1-k})}{(2p^4+8p^{2+2k})-(2p^4+8p^{2-2k})}\\
&=&\frac{(4-p^2)(p^k-p^{-k})}{2p(p^{2k}-p^{-2k})}=\frac{4-p^2}{2p(p^k+p^{-k})}.
\end{eqnarray*}
If $p=2$ then the slope equals $0$ for all $k$, so all these lines are parallel. However, if $p\neq2$ then the slope varies as $k$ varies, and the lines are *not* parallel.

In fact, your observation becomes a lot less astonishing after a projective transformation.

Consider the hyperbola in $\Bbb{R}^2$ given by $y=\frac{1}{x}$. Take two points $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $ab=1$. The vertical projections of $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ onto the hyperbola are given by $(a,\frac{1}{a})$ and $(b,\frac{1}{b})$. The line connecting these two points has slope $-1$. This is geometrically clear because the hyperbola is symmetric in the line $x=y$, and algebraically because $b=\frac{1}{a}$. The picture below shows the projection lines in black, and the connecting lines in yellow, for $a=2$ and $a=4$.

[image]

Applying the projective transformation
$$(x:y:z)\ \longmapsto\ (2z:2y:x+y),$$
now yields your picture, and a simple scaling yields a similar picture for any real number; this is not a property of any $p$-adic valuation, but a property of (real) conics.